# How to create a guard in Typescript for keys in a nested object?

Tags: typescript

I have a nested object that contains an object with multiple optional properties. I would like to create a typeguard to prevent the `Object is possibly undefined`. I do not know if this is possible or that I should cast it.

```
type PossibleKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type MappedObject = {
  test: {
    [key in PossibleKeys]?: { foo: boolean };
  }
}
const mappedObject: MappedObject = {
  test: {
    a: { foo: true },
    b: { foo: false },
  }
}

function mappedObjectHasKeyDefined(possibleKey: PossibleKeys): possibleKey is keyof MappedObject['test'] {
  return possibleKey in mappedObject.test;
}

const c: PossibleKeys = 'c';
const array: PossibleKeys[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array.forEach((newT: PossibleKeys) => {
  // all of these guards somehow do not seem to work
  if(
    mappedObject.test[newT] !== undefined 
    && newT in mappedObject.test 
    && mappedObject.test
    && mappedObject.test[newT]
    && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mappedObject.test, newT)
    && mappedObjectHasKeyDefined(newT)
  ) {
    // Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    const a = mappedObject.test[newT].foo;
  }
})
```

[Link to the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3&ssl=36&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigHIBDYqAHxNQuuIGNiBuAKFdEigFlSxIAJgHlUAKwgNghKAG9WUKMAgJgALlnyFUANoBrXFGQA7WIhQZsuBAF0A-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)

Comment: It seems just like a scope issue, usally you should use the keys/object in the predicate :

function mappedObjectHasKeyDefined(key: PossibleKeys, obj: MappedObject): obj is { test: { [K in typeof key]: any } } {
  return obj.test[key] !== undefined;
}

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/weazXw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @bitmanner do you use exactOptionalPropertyTypes?

Comment: @Tld The problem of using [K in typeof key]: any. Is that the compiler assumes that `c` is defined as property. Which isn`t the case.

Comment: @Dimava No I do not use the exactOptionalPropertyTypes option.

Comment: @jcalz The approach you went with is probably the approach I am going for. But not what I wanted. I wanted to know if it is possible to make a type guard for the key in the mappedObject.

Comment: Not directly, no.  Since the key is not of a single literal type then checking the property doesn't act as a type guard.  This is being tracked at [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) (although the original issue name doesn't quite apply anymore).  Does that address the question fully now? If so I'll write up an answer with this also.  Otherwise, what remains unanswered?

Comment: @jcalz That answers the question fully now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the apparent types of property accesses of the form `obj[key]` when `key` is not of a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  If `key` is just of type `string`, or if it's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string literal types (like `PossibleKeys`) or if it's a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, the compiler will not narrow the type of the property.  This is still an open feature request, tracked at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).

Currently the workaround is to copy the property into a new variable, since variables *can* be narrowed via checks.  Here's one way to do it:

```
array.forEach((newT: PossibleKeys) => {
  const t = mappedObject.test; // okay
  const u = t[newT]; // okay
  if (u) {
    const a = u.foo // okay
  }
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigHIBDYqAHxNQuuIGNiBuAKFdEigFlSxIAJgHlUAKwgNghKAG9WUKMAgJgALlnyFUANoBrXFGQA7WIhQZsuBAF0A-OplQAZnDjrUrzKRMBfNgp9WQIY4IxUoAFs+QRFxSXVefghhMQkpIjkFJRUHTQVSB2dXdWAAJwBXaB8AGjyoVEKXN2dSdAQq2oCg9hCwqVJS0tIQdXgkNEwcPG1raW0yYmqaRZImazYBoZAAOhdSgFFSBgALAApTowgAdwAVUbMJyzwASkIAPg0FXvD0yOjk2JpbbZYD+KDfKTlaTAbSXW7rTTIJxQU7lV6ZLQQqCkaTlXauTSBHzPdhAA)